# What is a good MySQL Database Schema tool?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I'm starting a new project soon and I'd like to try to use some better tools this time around. The last project, I wrote all my Database creation SQL by hand for MySQL. I'm hoping there are some good tools out there for creating, maintaining and modifying database schema in MySQL. My budget is out-of-my-own-pocket, so free (as in beer) would probably be best. :)

Comment: You can do this easily with dbForge Studio for MySQL. The complete list of features, please check out at https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/features.html  
The free Express edition is available as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MySQL Workbench : http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/

It is free and very easy to use. I usually create schema diagrams and export it as a .sql file to use with phpMyAdmin

Comment: I hadn't tried this one before because it didn't have a Linux version. New project allows me to use Windows if I want. So far this tool seems pretty easy to use. Already made a pretty basic schema.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "good" though - it crashes randomly and you lose your work (version 5.2.47 on Ubuntu)

Comment: +1 for mysql workbench; although I agree with @HorusKol that it does crash often.  However, at least in version 6 (available in .deb from their site), it does a good job of autosaving your work.

Answer (score 4):

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html offers a list of GUI tools to use.

Answer (score 3):

Mac options, try Querious or Sequel Pro - here's a comparison:

http://theappleblog.com/2009/02/27/mysql-showdown-querious-vs-sequel-pro/

Answer (score 2):

A complete list of data modeling tools can be found at [databaseanwers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench 5.1 (Beta 1) should be out March 6,2009. It will be available on MacOS, Fedora, Ubuntu, Windows. These are *native* C++ implementations on each platform. WB 5.1 is focused on Data Modeling (replacing Mike Zinner’s popular DBDesigner product).

MySQL Workbench 5.2 (Alpha 1) should be out mid April 2009 (around the MySQL Users Conference 2009). This will include a ground up rewrite of the MySQL Query Browser.

http://forums.mysql.com/index.php?151

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but this is too good to miss out on. I've only just found out about this recently...
[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com)

It supports connecting through SSH tunnels. It uses PuTTY (plink.exe) to do this but avoids having to manually fiddle with your PuTTY settings. It's even easier if you're using this nice portable version of PuTTY... http://jakub.kotrla.net/putty/

Plus it's open source. I strongly urge you to donate though as it's a great tool.

Another one that looks good is [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/)

I used to really like MySQL Administrator but the new Workbench is way too bloated. I just want a quick way to browse the schema without having to `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

Answer (score 0):

Use DB Schema editor but it is not freeware. But you can trial it for 15 days for free by downloading [here](http://www.dbschema.com/download.html)